# org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource hibernate.hbm.xml. Why am I getting it?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping, pojo

While trying to write a text file to the database, I get the following exception :

```
org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document 
from resource hibernate.hbm.xml
```

as soon as I click the `html` submit button :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="FileHandler">
        <input type="file" name="file" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

I don't know the reason for why am I getting it. Following is the *hibernate mapping file :*

```
    <hibernate-mapping>
      <class name="pojo.File" table="b_files"/>
        <id name="serial_number">
      <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="file" />
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Following is the class inside the `pojo package`  *(The mapping class)* :

```
package pojo;

public class File {
    private byte file[] = new byte[5120];
    private int serial_number;

    public int getSerial_number() {
        return serial_number;
    }

    public void setSerial_number(int serial_number) {
        this.serial_number = serial_number;
    }

    public byte[] getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(byte[] file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

}
```

I used the this command to make a table named `b_files` :

```
create table b_files(files_uploaded mediumblob, serial_number integer);
```

*Note :  What I guess, is a problem with a property named 'file' in the mapping file. Is that Okay ? Because I do not get 'file' as a hint in my netbeans IDE. So I guess that it may the problem.*

Comment: and you are certain the mapping file is correctly named, in the correct directory, and has correct permissions?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus yeah.http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ftdi0m&s=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing class in the wrong place. `id` and the `property` should precede a `</class>`, not close class with shortcut in its original line.